# Mixing processes

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I hope this question is not off-topic, but I'm currently discovering the existence of mixing processes, which attempt to express the dependence between random variables using miscellaneous coefficients ($\alpha$, $\beta$, $\phi$ and $\rho$ are the ones I've met so far).

Are there any references you would advise that survey them, perhaps along with more or less concrete examples of situations where these various coefficients can be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following references by Richard C. Bradley:

- ["Basic Properties of Strong Mixing Conditions. A Survey and Some Open Questions"](http://www.emis.de/journals/PS/images/ps-2005-37baf3.pdf);
- ["Introduction to Strong Mixing Conditions, Volumes 1-3"](http://www.kendrickpress.com/MixingConditions.html).

I've only been able to have a look at the first one; not very intuitive (to me, at least), but still a great overview.